# Run batch file with psql command without password

Tags: postgresql, shell, connection, psql

I am trying to execute this `psql` command using a batch script:

```sh
psql --host=localhost --dbname=<dbname> --port=<Port Number>
     --username=<dbuser> --file=C:\PSQL_Script.txt --output=C:\PSQL_Output.txt
```

The problem is that it's asking for the password every time I execute the batch script. How can I password argument through the batch file?

Answer (score 59):

Keep reading, the ***best options come last***. But let's clarify a couple of things first.

#### Only silence the password request

If your issue is only the password prompt, you can silence it. I quote [the manual here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html):

> `-w`
>   `--no-password`
>
> Never issue a password prompt. If the server requires password authentication and
>   a password is not available by other means such as
>   a `.pgpass` file, the connection attempt will fail. This option can be
>   useful in batch jobs and scripts where no user is present to enter a password. (...)

#### You probably don't need a password

Normally this is unnecessary. The default database superuser `postgres` usually corresponds to the system user of the same name. Running `psql` from this account doesn't require a password if the [authentication method **`peer`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER) or `ident` are set in your **`pg_hba.conf`** file. You probably have a line like this:

```sh
local    all    postgres    peer
```

And usually also:

```sh
local    all    all         peer
```

This means, every *local* user can log into a *all* database as database user of the same name without password.
**However**, there is a common misconception here. [Quoting again](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER):

> This method is only supported on **local connections**.

Bold emphasis mine.
You are connecting to **`localhost`**, which is **not a "local connection"**, even though it has the word "local" in it. It's a TCP/IP connection to 127.0.0.1. [Wikipedia on localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost):

> On modern computer systems, `localhost` as a hostname translates to an
>   IPv4 address in the `127.0.0.0/8` (loopback) net block, usually `127.0.0.1`, or `::1` in IPv6.

#### Simple solution for local connections

Omit the parameter `-h` from the `psql` invocation. Quoting [the manual on `psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-CONNECTING) once more:

> If you omit the host name, psql will connect **via a Unix-domain socket**
>   to a server on the local host, or via TCP/IP to `localhost` on machines
>   that don't have Unix-domain sockets.

#### Windows

... doesn't have Unix-domain sockets, `pg_hba.conf` lines starting with `local` are not applicable on Windows. On Windows you connect via `localhost` by default, which brings us back to the start.

If your security requirements are lax, you could just trust all connections via `localhost`:

```sh
host    all    all    127.0.0.1/32     trust
```

I would only do that for debugging with remote connections off. For some more security you can use [SSPI authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#SSPI-AUTH) on Windows. Add this line to `pg_hba.conf` for "local" connections:

```sh
host    all    all    127.0.0.1/32     sspi
```

#### If you actually need a password

You *could* set an **environment variable**, but this is ***discouraged***, especially for Windows. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html)

> `PGPASSWORD` behaves the same as the [password](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-PASSWORD) connection 
>   parameter. Use of this environment variable is not recommended
>   for security reasons, as some operating systems allow non-root
>   users to see process environment variables via ps; instead
>   consider using the `~/.pgpass` file (see [Section 32.15](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html)).

[The manual on `psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-CONNECTING):

A [**`conninfo`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) string is an alternative to specify connection parameters:

```sh
 $ psql "user=myuser password=secret_pw host=localhost port=5432 sslmode=require"
```

Or a [**URI**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#id-1.7.3.8.3.6), which is used instead of a database name:

```sh
 $ psql postgresql://myuser:secret_pw@localhost:5432/mydb?sslmode=require
```

### Password File

But it's usually preferable to set up a [**`.pgpass` file**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) rather than putting passwords into script files.
Read the [short chapter in the manual carefully](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html). In particular, note that here ...

> A host name of `localhost` matches both TCP (host name `localhost`) and Unix domain socket (`pghost` empty or the default socket directory) connections coming from the local machine.

Exact path depends on the system. This file can store passwords for multiple combinations of role and port (DB cluster):

```sh
localhost:5432:*:myadmin:myadminPasswd
localhost:5434:*:myadmin:myadminPasswd
localhost:5437:*:myadmin:myadminPasswd
...
```

On **Windows** machines look for the file in:

```
%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf
```

`%APPDATA%` typically resolves to: `C:\Documents and Settings\My_Windows_User_Name\Application Data\`.

Answer (score 1):

I had kinda same problem:

```
psql -hlocalhost -d<myDB> -U<myUser>
```

always prompted me for password. This is as @Erwin explained because of `-hlocalhost` is connecting through TCP and not through the Unix-domain socket (for Unix based OS). So even if you've configured your `local` as trusted:

```
local   all    all                     trust
```

it will still prompt for password. So in order to configure the `-hlocalhost` to work through TCP I had to configure the `host` for localhost addresses, like so:

```
host    all    all    127.0.0.1/32     trust
host    all    all    ::1/128          trust
```

But this didn't work for me. What I had to do is combine both of those as:

```
host    all    all    localhost        trust
```

Some additional readings:

- [Configuring pg_hba.conf file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)
- [Authentication methods: trust, peer, ident, etc.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-methods.html)

Answer (score 0):

postgres Documentation - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html

-w
--no-password
Never issue a password prompt. If the server requires password authentication and a password is not available by other means such as a .pgpass file, the connection attempt will fail. This option can be useful in batch jobs and scripts where no user is present to enter a password.

Answer (score 0):

I found this hack of passing a connection string to command i.e.

```
$ psql postgresql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}
```

`Example:

```
$ psql postgresql://user:password@127.0.0.1:5432/database
```

This way, if you have to pass in the database password but you don't want to keep on passing it in the prompt, you can just do this in your bash file.