# Capistrano postgresql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, deployment, capistrano, unicorn

I am deploying an app to digital ocean for the first time and ran into two (possible more) issues.

1) I can't `bundle install` after adding `gem 'unicorn'` to Gemfile. I found that kgio is not compatible with windows. Do I have to have Gemfile.lock present when I deploy via capistrano? How would I work around this issue?

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.14.1'
  gem "nginx"
  gem 'unicorn'
end
```

2) I am having trouble with authentication on postgresql on the server.

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: postgresql
  pool: 5
  username: postgresql
  password: secret
```

I ran these commands (along with some other variations):

```
create user postgresql with password 'secret';
create database postgresql with owner postgresql;
```

Every time I cap deploy, I get this error:

```
FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgresql"
```

I tried putting an invalid username that I know doesn't exist, a database that is invalid but the error message is always the same. According to postgresql website, I should be getting different errors for those...

If I can get some help, that'd be amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify the host for the password authentication.

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: postgresql
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: postgresql
  password: secret
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942485/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres/11545725#11545725)

Answer (score 2):

You have to set up Postgres for ***password*** or ***md5*** (safer: ***scram-sha-256*** since Postgres 11) [authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PASSWORD) first - in the [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file.

As long as only [***ident** or **peer** authentication*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER) is allowed, passwords are not prompted. You are only allowed to log in as the db role corresponding to your system user.

BTW, database role and OS user are typically called ***postgres***, not *postgresql*. That's not a typo there, I assume?

Try in a shell:

```
sudo -u postgres -i
```

And then log in as `postgres` db role with peer authentication.

See:

- [PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist/11919677#11919677)
- [Run batch file with psql command without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100)