# How to provide password in one script to connect to postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

I want to backup my postgresql database with a automatic backup program and that program only support a script line that backup with pg_dump.
I can't provide password in this script so I changed method from pg_hba.conf file from md5 to trust so that it won't ask for password and I used --no-password option.
How can I change this to md5 and provide password for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6405127/330315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [`.pgpass` file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html) or use the `peer` authentication method. Details here:
[Run batch file with psql command without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100)