# Restore a PostgreSQL database without setting the password in the environment

Tags: python, postgresql, passwords, connection

I need to make a script in python that calls `pg_restore` to restore a database. So far I use a batch file that sets true password in `PGPASSWORD` and after the restore it sets garbage in the var.

My problem is that I have to create a environment variable with `SET PGPASSWORD='password'` but I can't expose the password in the environment because if there is an error in the restore, `PGPASSWORD` will have the true password.

Is there a way to send the restore command with the password, like one can do with firebird?

Using Windows XP/7/8 with PostgreSQL 9.x.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use a [**`.pgpass`** file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html).

> On Microsoft Windows the file is named
>   `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` (where `%APPDATA%` refers to the
>   Application Data subdirectory in the user's profile)

You *could* set an **environment variable**, but you are right in trying to avoid that. [It's discouraged in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-envars.html):

> `PGPASSWORD` behaves the same as the password connection parameter. Use
>   of this environment variable is not recommended for security reasons,
>   as some operating systems allow non-root users to see process
>   environment variables via ps; instead consider using the `~/.pgpass` file

More about access without password:
[Run batch file with psql command without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100)

Comment: Erwin, good point re `PGPASSWORD` in your comment; might be worth adding here.

Comment: @CraigRinger: The quote is in the earlier answer I linked to. But following your advice I added it here, too.