# Postgresql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "rooms"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, connection

I just installed rails and postgresql (by following [this](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04) tutorial) on a new computer and I'm trying to run a rails app that had been previously made and is working and in production. However, once I tried running the app, I received this error:

```
 /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `initialize': FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "rooms" (PG::ConnectionBad)
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "rooms"
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `new'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `connect'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:324:in `initialize'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:310:in `clear_cache!'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__3258742772582479979__prepare__847046652929319931__callbacks'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/andrew/Documents/mywebroom/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/andrew/Documents/mywebroom/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/andrew/Documents/mywebroom/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/andrew/Documents/mywebroom/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Here's what my `database.yml` file looks like:

```
development:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    host: localhost
    database: rooms_development
    pool: 5
    username: rooms
    password: rooms
```

I'm still new to rails and I have no idea how to fix this - please help!

Comment: The password you supplied does not match the password PostgreSQL has on record for the user `rooms`. Use the correct password or reset it in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

That's Postgres telling you the login with password failed. [The manual advises:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/client-authentication-problems.html)

> Messages like this indicate that you contacted the server, and it is
>   willing to talk to you, but not until you pass the authorization
>   method specified in the `pg_hba.conf` file. Check the password you are
>   providing, or check your Kerberos or ident software if the complaint
>   mentions one of those authentication types.

More advice there ...
Or in this related answer:

- [Run batch file with psql command without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same problem on Ubuntu machine so I removed it by using following steps.

From console switch to postgres user

`$ sudo su - postgres`

it will ask for password and by default password is `postgres`

After switch the user to postgres, open psql console

```
$ psql
```

so check the version of postgres if multiple versions are available

```
psql=# select VERSION();

PostgreSQL 9.1.13 on x86_64-unk....         # so version is 9.1
```

Now Open `postgres user`

`vim /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf`

`9.1` is version return form upper command

and replace

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

to

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
```

I write steps on my blog also

http://tarungarg402.blogspot.in/2014/10/set-up-postgresql-on-ubuntu.html