# psql - every command returns FATAL: role "username" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, linux-mint

I installed postgresql server on Linux Mint, however, all I get from it is

> "FATAL:  role "username" does not exist".

I've tried the following commands (probably some more):

```
psql
psql --list
psql \du
psql \l
psql -d template1
createuser -s -r postgres
```

Same thing happens if I switch the user to postgres:

```
su - postgres
```

The postgresql version is 9.3.

What's the correct approach on solving this? Thanks.

Comment: I've written a [blog](http://zedfox.us/blog/install-postsgresql-9-6-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-and-reset-postgres-password/) recently regarding this. I hope a couple of strategies help you. Try editing /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf and changing the last bit of this line`local   all   postgres   peer`. Change from `peer` to `trust`. Restart postgres and see if you can log on with `psql -U postgres`

Answer (score 0):

By default a *database user* `postgres` is created on installation. You should be able to connect without password as *system user* `postgres`.

- [PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist/11919677#11919677)

**[Peer authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER)** must be enabled, of course:

- [Run batch file with psql command without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100)