# Postgres not allowing localhost but works with 127.0.0.1

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, connection

Postgres not accepting connection if I say `-h localhost` but it works if I say `-h 127.0.0.1`

```
[root@5d9ca0effd7f opensips]# psql -U postgres -h localhost -W
Password for user postgres:
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
[root@5d9ca0effd7f opensips]# psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1 -W
Password for user postgres:
psql (8.4.20)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

My `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf`

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                              trust
local   all         all                              ident
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               ident
```

If I add following line then Postgres service `failed` to start:

```
host    all         all        localhost             ident
host    all         all        localhost             trust
```

Wwhat is wrong there?

#### Update

My `/etc/hosts` file:

```
[root@5d9ca0effd7f opensips]# cat /etc/hosts
172.17.0.2      5d9ca0effd7f
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: My guess:  localhost is not defined as a network alias for 127.0.0.1.  I see "local" in your config file but not "localhost".

Comment: Also can you check your /etc/host for loopback address?

Comment: it is there `127.0.0.1       localhost` in `/etc/hosts` also i have updated my question

Comment: Obviously you must provide your version of Postgres. Is it 8.4 like your psql? BTW,  "Postgress" is not a valid name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In pg_hba.conf, the **first match** counts. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

> The first record with a matching connection type, client address,
> requested database, and user name is used to perform authentication.
> There is no "fall-through" or "backup": if one record is chosen and
> the authentication fails, subsequent records are not considered. If no
> record matches, access is denied.

Note the **reversed order**:

```
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          ident
```

But:

```
host    all         all        localhost             ident
host    all         all        localhost             trust
```

Remember to **reload** after saving changes to `pg_hba.conf`. (Restart is not necessary.) [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

> The `pg_hba.conf` file is read on start-up and when the main server
> process receives a `SIGHUP` signal. If you edit the file on an active
> system, you will need to signal the postmaster (using `pg_ctl reload`,
> calling the SQL function `pg_reload_conf()`, or using `kill -HUP`) to
> make it re-read the file.

If you really "add" the lines like you wrote, there should not be any effect at all. But if you **replace** the lines, there is.

In the first case, you get `trust` authentication method, which is an open-door policy. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-methods.html#AUTH-TRUST)

> PostgreSQL assumes that anyone who can connect to the server is
> authorized to access the database with whatever database user name
> they specify (even superuser names)

But in the second case you get the [`ident` authentication method](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT), which has to be set up properly to work.

Plus, [as Cas pointed out later](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46645809/939860), `localhost` covers both IPv4 and IPv6, while `127.0.0.1/32` only applies to IPv4.

If you are actually using the outdated version 8.4, go to the [old manual for 8.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT). You are aware that [8.4 has reached EOL in 2014](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) and is not supported any more? Consider upgrading to a current version.

In Postgres 9.1 or later you would rather use **`peer`** than `ident`.

More:

- [Run batch file with psql command without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100)

Comment: it was `8.4` now i have upgraded to `9.4` and getting error now `psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"`  I have put `ident` first in `pg_hba.conf` file. also i have changed `postgres` password but not allowing me to get in.

Comment: Holy cow!! its works when i change to `host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5` How????

Comment: @Satish: Because `md5` is a completely different authentication method. Read a bit in the manual, I provided links. In Postgres 9.1 or later you would also rather use `peer` than `ident`.

Answer (score 13):

### The Problem

Postgres will potentially use **IPv6** when specifying `-h localhost` which given the above `pg_hba.conf` specifies `ident`, a password prompt will be returned.

However when `-h 127.0.0.1` is specified, it forces Postgres to use **IPv4**, which is set to `trust` in above config and allows access without password.

---

### The Answer

Thus the answer is to modify the IPv6 host line in `pg_hba.conf` to use `trust`:

```
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
```

*Remembering to restart the Postgres service after making config changes.*