# Postgres not allowing `127.0.0.1` but works with `localhost`

Tags: postgresql, docker, macos-big-sur

Postgres is ran in a container, using `postgres:14.1-alpine` image.

When ran **A) with [`--network host`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-host)**, then

```
PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -d db -U postgres -h localhost  # works 
PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -d db -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1  # fails
```

When ran **B) without `--network host`**, then both hosts above work.

The error is

```
psql: error: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: 
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Why would `-h 127.0.0.1` in **A)** fail? I've provided details below. What else should one check?

### Exact replay of commands

Run both containers **pgA** and **pgB**:

```bash
> docker run -d --rm -it --network host \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -ePOSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=db \
  --name pgA \
  postgres:14.1-alpine

OUTPUT: <containerA_id>


> docker run -d --rm -it \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -ePOSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=db \
  --name pgB \
  postgres:14.1-alpine

OUTPUT: <containerB_id>
```

Try to connect to both using `-h 127.0.0.1`:

```
> docker exec -it \
  pgA \
  bash -c ' PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -h 127.0.0.1 -d db -U postgres'

OUTPUT: psql: error: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: 
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"


> docker exec -it \
  pgB \
  bash -c ' PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -h 127.0.0.1 -d db -U postgres'

OUTPUT: psql (14.1)
Type "help" for help.

db=#
```

### Env

```
> docker --version
Docker version 20.10.11, build dea9396

> uname -a
Darwin foo.local 20.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: 
Mon Aug 30 06:12:20 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.6~3/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64
```

### Comparisons between the two containers `pgA` and `pgB`

- All *files* that are direct descendants of `/var/lib/postgresql/data/` are identical (except for the different PID in `postmaster.pid`). For   example, `postgresql.conf` contains

  ```
  listen_addresses = '*'
  ```

  in both **A)** and **B)** container.

  Similarly, `pg_hba.conf` is identical

  ```
  local   all             all                                     trust
  # IPv4 local connections:
  host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
  # IPv6 local connections:
  host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
  # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
  # replication privilege.
  local   replication     all                                     trust
  host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
  host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
  ```

  (Child *directories* of `/var/lib/postgresql/data/`, such as `pg_wal/`, `base/`, etc. are likely different - haven't checked.)
- `netstat -anpt | grep 5432` is identical

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*            LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::5432                 :::*                 LISTEN
```

- `/etc/hosts` is almost identical ...

  ```
  127.0.0.1       localhost
  ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  fe00::0 ip6-localnet
  ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
  ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
  ```

  ... except that **B) with `--network   bridge`**, this line is appended:

  ```
  <container_ip>    <container_id>
  ```

### Related questions

- an exact opposite problem: [Postgres not allowing localhost but works with 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802440/postgres-not-allowing-localhost-but-works-with-127-0-0-1)
- [similar #1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/216465/i-can-not-get-postgres-to-listen-on-anything-but-localhost)
- [similar #2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105042/why-does-connecting-to-127-0-0-1-work-whilst-localhost-fails)

Comment: In postgresql.conf, listen_address... what you see?

Comment: `listen_addresses = '*' ` in both containers. In fact, all files that are direct children of `/var/lib/postgresql/data/` are identical, bar the PID. (I've updated the answer.)

Comment: Look in the db log file for the a more detailed error message about the password failure.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, but I don't have a Mac so am using "Docker version 20.10.12, build 20.10.12-0ubuntu4".

Comment: What if you try ::1 rather than 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly oversight of not realising that yet another, a third PG instance had already bridge-bound the `HostPort` 5432.

Thanks to @jjanes for the logs and IPv6 hints. For the posterity, check your logs!

`LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "0.0.0.0": Address in use`