# How to reindex Postgres 9.1.3 from the command line

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, reindex

I have a series of deletes and updates on a few tables in a Postgres database I manage. It has been suggested to schedule a reindex after the series of deletes as a solution to the 10 minute next-step update freezing infinitely (as it randomly does.) The DOS instructions provide this:

```
Usage:
  reindexdb [OPTION]... [DBNAME]

Options:
  -a, --all                 reindex all databases
  -d, --dbname=DBNAME       database to reindex
  -e, --echo                show the commands being sent to the server
  -i, --index=INDEX         recreate specific index only
  -q, --quiet               don't write any messages
  -s, --system              reindex system catalogs
  -t, --table=TABLE         reindex specific table only
  --help                    show this help, then exit
  --version                 output version information, then exit

Connection options:
  -h, --host=HOSTNAME       database server host or socket directory
  -p, --port=PORT           database server port
  -U, --username=USERNAME   user name to connect as
  -w, --no-password         never prompt for password
  -W, --password            force password prompt
```

We have to use version 9.1.3 as this is the corporate standard.
 I have tried every option I can think of but it won't take the command to reindex:

```
reindexdb.exe -U username=MyUserName -W MyPassword -t table=MyDatabase.MyTable
```

I've also tried

```
reindexdb.exe -U MyUserName -W MyPassword -t MyDatabase.MyTable
```

and

```
reindexdb.exe -U MyUserName -W MyPassword -t MyTable -d MyDatabase
```

...but they all end with the error:

```
reindexdb: too many command-line arguments (first is "-t")
```

Does anyone have a working sample that would be able to clarify what the right syntax is?

Comment: Use the password file, on Windows: %APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15593100/939860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did it:

```
reindexdb.exe -d MyDatabase -U postgres -t MyTable
```

As @Colonel Thirty Two and @Erwin Brandstetter noted, removing the password entirely is possible through %APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf

Answer (score 5):

Remove `MyPassword` from your arguments, and enter it in when Postgres prompts you for it.

`-W` simply causes Postgres to prompt for the password; it doesn't accept the password itself. You should never specify passwords on the command line, as it's usually logged.

If you need to run it non-interactively, either set the [`PGPASSWORD` environment variable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-envars.html) or create a [`pgpass` file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-pgpass.html).

Comment: If this is in a scheduled task batch file, how would I account for entering the password in a non-interactive environment?

Answer (score 2):

Any of these can be forced by adding the keyword FORCE after the command

Recreate a single index, myindex:

```
REINDEX INDEX myindex
```

Recreate all indices in a table, mytable:

```
REINDEX TABLE mytable
```

Recreate all indices in schema public:

```
REINDEX SCHEMA public
```

Recreate all indices in database postgres:

```
REINDEX DATABASE postgres
```

Recreate all indices on system catalogs in database postgres:

```
REINDEX SYSTEM postgres
```

[link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/optimize-and-improve-postgresql-performance-with-vacuum-analyze-and-reindex-885239781.html)