# psql: FATAL: role "vimarshchaturvedi" does not exist. Postgres.app installation

Tags: macos, postgresql, authentication, postgresql-9.6

I am working on OS X El Capitan version 10.11.3
I downloaded the Postgres app and ran the app.

The elephant icon on the top says Version 9.6.1.0(9.6.1.0)

When I click on 'Open psql' I get the following output on my terminal.

```
$ '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin'/psql -p5432
psql: FATAL:  role <username> does not exist
```

where  is my username. As far as I understand the app should create a role with my username and no password.

I tried doing:

```
psql -h localhost -U <username>
```

which gave the same error.

Following are the various output I got for trying out answers posted on SO.

```
$ which psql
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/psql
```

After searching a bit more I ran the following command:

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres
postgres=#
```

The postgres shell opened up. Can anyone explain what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Starting psql without any given username (`-U ...`) tries to log in with a db user of the same name as the current OS user. Obviously that DB user has not yet been created.

- [PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist/11919677#11919677)

The default superuser created with every DB cluster is named `postgres`. Don't confuse this with the name of the RDBMS or the system DB named `postgres` other other uses.

The fact that you can log in with user `postgres` and no PW indicates 2 things:

1. The user `postgres exists (duh).
2. It's set up for password-less access, either with a `.pgpass` file or in `pg_hba.conf` with one of the authentication methods `peer` , `ident` or `trust`. `peer` most likely.

If so, as quick fix from the shell:

```
createuser -h localhost -U postgres vimarshchaturvedi
```

`vimarshchaturvedi` obviously being your OS username.

- [Run batch file with psql command without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100)

Once logged in, you can check which *login roles* (= users) exit:

```
SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles;
```