# Run query via batch file in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, batch-file

Hello expert I want to refresh materialized view in postgresql via batch file. I don't have any idea how to connect postgresql  database via batch file. I have to run following query via batch file - "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW  deposit.mv_transaction_view"

Answer (score 3):

Update: based on comments, filled in all the parameters required to connect to a database "planet" with user, port and password information.  The quotes are really for the shell, for easy replacement.

You can do this with `psql`.

```
psql -Upostgres -p5432 -c "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW deposit.mv_transaction_view" planet
```

and put that in the batch file or script or whatever.

With this in your `~/.pgpass` file:

```
localhost:5432:planet:postgres:pes
```

or variants thereof.  You can also use

```
*:*:*:postgres:pes
```

Comment: I need the full answer with example. how to connect with database.

Comment: This is the full example.  On my machine this works `psql -c "select version()"` You can add `--host=hostname`, `--port=portnum`, `--username=username` and `dbname` as standalone parameter.  Put your psasword in `~/.pgpass`.

Comment: If you don't mind i need the complete script for batch file example- i have a database "planet", user="postgres", password="pes", port="5432" and i want to run "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW deposit.mv_transaction_view" query.

Comment: Stack overflow is not an excuse not to read the manual.  However, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @JharanaGharti: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password and https://stackoverflow.com/q/6405127/330315