# .pgpass file for more than one user

Tags: postgresql, passwords, connection, postgresql-10

If I set `PGPASSFILE` to an explicit path like `/home/user/.pgpass` then it works fine and when logged in as the user that owns that file I can use `psql` for the entries in `.pgpass.conf`.

The problem I have is that I need to have multiple accounts use psql.  If I change `PGPASSFILE` to user directory like `~/.pgpass.conf` then it doesn't work and doesn't read the file so it gives a password error.

Because I can only specify one file it means only the owner of that file can run the commands I need to run.

I am running on Ubuntu 18.04 and I need root & www-data to have a `.pgpass.conf` file.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have *system* users corresponding to your *db* users (`root` and `www-data` in your case), each has its own, separate `.pgpass` file in its respective home directory. Set each accordingly.

And simply do **not** set `PGPASSFILE` at all. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/libpq-envars.html)

> `PGPASSFILE` behaves the same as the [passfile](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-PASSFILE) connection parameter.

[And:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-PASSFILE)

> `passfile`
>
> Specifies the name of the file used to store passwords (see [Section 33.15](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html)). Defaults to `~/.pgpass`, or
>   `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` on Microsoft Windows. (No error is
>   reported if this file does not exist.)

Related:

- [Run batch file with psql command without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100)